# How do you decide between different emerging technologies?

Tags: project-management

I'm facing developing a new web app in the future and I'm wondering how to decide what framework to use. I've settled on Python as my language of choice. But there are still may frameworks to choose from! More generally how do you choose between different similar technologies that are still in the works as the latest round of web frameworks are? I'm curious what your process is for deciding on technologies you've never used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recognize that no choice is perfect -- or even very good.

No matter what you choose, someone will have a suggestion that -- they claim -- is better.

No matter what you choose, some part of your tech. stack will fail to live up to your expectations.

The most important thing is "shared nothing" so that the components can be replaced.

After that, the next most important thing is automatically-generated features to reduce or prevent programming.

Look at Django.  Lots of automatic admin features make life very pleasant.

Comment: What do you mean by "shared nothing" ? Django is actually one of the two major contenders at the moment. The other is Pylons.

Comment: http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter20/ -- "shared nothing is really just the application of loose coupling to the entire software stack" more good stuff here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can do:

- Download the frameworks and build something similar with them for comparison.
- Look for comparisons by other people, but attempt to understand the bias of the reviewer.
- Observe the community at work, see what people are building and the issues they run into when using the technology. Forums, blogs, mailing list etc are good places to check out.
- Go to conferences and meet like minded developers interested.

You can also take the approach of using stable versions rather than alpha bits. After a while you might move closer the bleeding edge. People associated with the project in question are generally more biased than those approaching from other platforms, be careful who you trust.

Consider the impact of using a bleeding edge framework versus an established one. Sometimes it's important to your customers that you are on one perceived as stable. At other times this doesn't matter. How comfortable are you with fixing the framework itself? Great developers will learn the internals, or at least know enough to keep things moving whilst a bug is sent to the framework mailing list etc.

Consider some general best practices in building abstractions and reusable code on the python platform. You may be able to save yourself some work in moving to another platform. However, don't be a reuse junkie as this can limit the effectiveness of your use of the framework. The 37Signals guys are right when they talk about extracting frameworks from working code rather than building frameworks from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old posting, but I am in a similar situation (again) and I think there are other people who may want to look for different opinions, and hear of (somewhat) successful experiences.

Since baudtack mentioned Python, I will try to answer this along the lines of my experiences using Python. Here is what has been working for me:

1. determine the scope of your project - outlining what your application is supposed to be able to do without introducing any programming or design notes will clarify your goals greatly
2. determine how you would like to work with your code, stack and data:

   a. what sort of programming paradigm do you want to work with? i.e. object-oriented, functional, etc. do you want to play to your programming style or do you want to follow somebody else's programming style?

   b. use semantic web or not? do you want greater control over URIs and their design? (I found web.py great for this by the way - It is my choice to create REST APIs in Python)

   c. do you want to be trapped by framework requirements, or do you want a better separation of the application from the web component, i.e. use a framework to utilize your application as a set of modules, for example. My problem with Django was that I ended up not programming Python, but having to learn more Django than I needed to. If that works for you, then that is the way to go.

   d. data stores... some sort of SQL vs. non RDBMS (xml databases like eXist-db with full xquery support) vs. OODBMS vs. a combination of the above? how complicated do you need this to be? how much control/separation do you need to have over how data gets stored and recalled in your application?

   e. testing: unit tests... thank goodness for python! if your web app has the potential to grow (as they often do), having a sane and coherent testing platform to begin with will help out a lot in the future - I wish I had learned about this earlier on. oh well... better late than never.

   f. how much control over the server do you need? hosting considerations? how much control over an Apache instance do you need to have? OS specific needs? I found that using shared hosting providers like Webfaction has been great. I eventually found I needed greater needs for flexibility and bandwidth. In other words, what can you get for your budget? If you have USD50 to spend each month, it may be better to consider a virtual hosting solution like Linode....

Finally, I echo S.Lott's sentiments that no choice for a solution is perfect, and are subject to obsolescence.

Answer (score 1):

Experience trumps hearsay.  I've found that prototyping is a huge help.  Make a prototype that uses the features you expect to be the most important for various frameworks.  This helps route out any features that may not work "as advertised."

In general though, kudos for being willing to look at new technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I have a set of criteria in different categories:

**Activity & Documentation**

1. Is there an active user base?
2. Is there an active development base?
3. Is the support responsive and information accessible?
4. Are there user and development guides and reference material?

These are essential, there needs to be traceability of all of these to build confidence in the solution.

**Ease of use**

Are basic features easy and complex features possible?  I typically give a new framework a test drive and try to roll out a set of use cases to see how intuitive the framework is to use.

1. Is installation intuitive and simple for a local/dev installation and production deployment?
2. How is it backed up and upgraded?
3. What is the effort and UX for implementing a "Hello World" type blog post, static page, menu item, and plugin?
4. How are versions dealt with for the core & plugins?

**Example (on the topic of Automated Testing/Continuous Integration solutions)**

Several years ago I evaluated several Automated Testing solution.  At the time [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) were front runners and in the end I chose TeamCity because of the UX, active user & development base and quality of accessible documentation.

**Example (CMS for a blog)**

This criteria is also why I prefer to use Wordpress over other options.  While wordpress has its shortcomings, the user and development base is strong and active which leads to a software architecture with more potential to evolve over time and maintain its relevance and a development community that provides quality plugins and themes to choose from.